# RESTful API Entity Framework context repeating child collections data C#

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, rest, restful-architecture

I am using projection (explicit loading) to call and filter collections data returned from a child table, with the result exposed via a RESTful Api service. The json is fine but it repeats the child table collections object. Using "AsNoTracking()" method nulls the nested child collections in the json output which isn't right.

Here is my code below and the json output. I need help to stop the child object repeating

```
public IQueryable<ApiViewModel> getAllActive()
{
        //Explicit loading (projection)
        var result = db.Markets
            .Where(p => p.IsActive == true)
            .Select(p => new ApiViewModel()
            {
                Market = p,
                TravelCentres = p.TravelCentres.Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
            });

    return result;
}
```

JSON Output:

```
[
  {
    "Market": {
        "MarketId": "AE",
        "Name": "Arabian Emirates",
        "TravelCentres": [
            {
                "City": "New Lynn, New Zealand",
                "Address": "now",
                "Telephone": "09169647771",
                "Email": "test@wak.com"
            },
            {
                "City": "Uyo, Nigeria",
                "Address": "Ewet housing",
                "Telephone": null,
                "Email": null
            },
            {
                "City": "Lagos, Nigeria",
                "Address": "no",
                "Telephone": "09993",
                "Email": "patricko@wak.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    "TravelCentres": [
        {
            "City": "New Lynn, New Zealand",
            "Address": "now",
            "Telephone": "09169647771",
            "Email": "test@wak.com"
        },
        {
            "City": "Uyo, Nigeria",
            "Address": "Ewet housing",
            "Telephone": null,
            "Email": null
        },
        {
            "City": "Lagos, Nigeria",
            "Address": "no",
            "Telephone": "09993",
            "Email": "patricko@wak.com"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you using LazyLoading right? .. have you tried maybe to remap the Market in your projection so it doesn't load also the related TravelCentres in them?..or also .. can you use eagder loading instead lazy loading?

Comment: Thanks @federico for the response. I am using projection/explicit loading because eager loading cannot filter the child (TravelCentre) table. How do I remap the Market in the projection so it doesn't load also the related TravelCentres in them?

Comment: mmm can't you do with eagder loading something like:  var result = db.Markets
            .Where(p => p.IsActive == true).Include(xx=> xx.TravelCentres.Where(x => x.IsActive == true))
            .Select(p => new ApiViewModel
            {
                Market = p,
                
            });

Comment: it failed. "ExceptionMessage": "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.\r\nParameter name: path",

Comment: ah ok so TravelCentres is not a one to many reference ..but 1 - 1

Comment: it is. TravelCentres in the child collection object of Market 1-many

Comment: so how you can do TravelCentres = p.TravelCentres.Where(x => x.IsActive == true) in your porjection?? if it is not a collection?

Comment: I got it solved via eager loading using a 3rd party extension method to enable includefilter https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues. Thanks for your help @federico

Comment: If it help you rate it.. but only if it helps you!!.. very happy you risolved it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using eager loading with 3rd party IncludeFilter() extension method.
https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues

Answer (score 0):

Try Distinct() method.
also see above link
In [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx)